# Unable to add an object to array in another object of MongoDB, how to fix that?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My models:

coins.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {orderSchema} = require('./orders');
const coinSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        description: String,
        orders: [orderSchema],
        
    }
);

const Coin = mongoose.model('Coin',coinSchema);
module.exports = Coin
```

orders

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        description: String,
        purchasePrice: Number,
        purchaseCount: Number,
        purchaseAmount: Number,
        comission:Number
        
    }
);

const Order = mongoose.model('Order',orderSchema);
module.exports.Order = Order
module.exports.orderSchema = orderSchema
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs=require('ejs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Coin = require('./models/coins');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground')
.then(()=>console.log('connected'))
.catch(err => console.error('some error',err))

async function createCoin(){
const Coin = require('./models/coins');
const coin = new Coin(
    {
    name: 'BTT',
    description: 'Bittorrent coin',
    }
);

const result = await coin.save();
console.log(result);
}

createCoin()

async function createOrder(){
    const {Order} = require('./models/orders');
    const order = new Order(
        {
            purchasePrice: 0.54,
            purchaseCount: 200,
            purchaseAmount: 54000,
            comission:23
    
        }
    );
    
    const result = await order.save();
    addOrder('BTT',result)
    console.log(result);
    }
    
createOrder()

async function addOrder(coinName,order){
    const coin = await Coin.find({name:coinName});
    console.log("Writing to Coin:",coin.orders)
    console.log("Writing order:",order)
    coin.orders.push(order);
    coin.save();
}
```

The error I am getting

```
(node:5988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at addOrder (D:\CoinsPortal\index.js:48:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:5988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5988) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am trying to create two documents. Where coin document contains any array for orders.
And order is another document. So, I wrote addOrder function to add it to a coin with the name provided at the end of its creation.

But getting the above error while running it and both the documents are not getting linked in the mongodb, but they are creating.

Please suggest how to setup this relation.

Comment: `find()` method will return multiple documents in the array,  add yo have directly so this `coin.orders` will return undefined. you can loop `coin` and update inside loop, or if you are trying to select only one document then use `findOne()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  you need to change add the field named "orders" in Coin document.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

async function createCoin(){
    const Coin = require('./models/coins');
    const coin = new Coin(
        {
        name: 'BTT',
        description: 'Bittorrent coin',
        order: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        }
    );

    const result = await coin.save();
    console.log(result);
}
```

And then, please try to change the addOrder function as following.

```
async function addOrder(coinName,order){
    console.log('coinName', coinName)
    console.log('order', order._doc)
    const coin = await Coin.findOneAndUpdate(
        {name:coinName},
        {$push: {
            order: order._doc
            }}
        );
}
```

Here is the source code link that you can get. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fP10hc9ZrBVhYdPT4UhBKki9qq31sdQH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Getting this error. Any change I need to do for model of coin? UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Coin validation failed: orders: Cast to embedded failed for value "[Function: Mixed] {\n' +
  "  schemaName: 'Mixed',\n" +
  '  defaultOptions: {},\n' +
  '  get: [Function (anonymous)],\n' +
  '  set: [Function: set]\n' +
  '}" (type string) at path "orders"

Comment: Here is the source code link that you can download. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fP10hc9ZrBVhYdPT4UhBKki9qq31sdQH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working. Any suggestion on how to get all the orders aggregate values when the coin related to it is retrieved.

Comment: no problem, but can you explain the problem in detail? and can you accept my answer is correct and upvoted?

Comment: thank you. I have coin collection, each coin linked to mulitple orders as sub document. So, when a coin retrieved, it should get the avg of price field and the coins field.